# Spring MVC annotation driven classes vs pure commands

Tags: java, spring, architecture, command, inversion-of-control

I have to say that I find the annotation-driven model of Spring MVC convenient, but coming from the Flex world, I am very much used to using the Command design pattern. It makes it very easy to reduce the levels of abstraction, and achieve flexibility by extending generic command functionality. However, I find it difficult to fit this into the Spring environment.

In the ideal case, there should be no controllers but one generic HandleWebRequestCommand class, which, based on the request params (or URL path vars) executes another command (or a chain of commands). Other commands will be responsible for calling remote services, handling the DB retrieval/persistence, file manipulation, etc. This will reduce the whole Controller/Service/Persistence cake to a set of interchangeable and uncoupled commands.

The hardest part by far seems to be making the mappings between what is happening and which commands should be executed. I see an XML context-like file very appropriate for this purpose where all the commands are declared. Also, their dependencies will be supplied (Every command might have a set of other commands that it depends on (interfaced, of course)) So far, I don't envision the use of an event-driven architecture, since most of the commands will still be executed as a result of HTTP request, so the most important mappings will be those within the HandleWebRequestCommand

I am confused. Please help. Should I keep fitting this Spring, or start developing my own architecture directly on top of Java EE? Is such an architecture OK at all?

Answer (score 4):

I think you're not yet seeing Spring for what it is.

The "one generic `HandleWebRequestCommand` class" already exists--it's how things are routed to your controllers. "Commands" are (roughly) services, and can be created and combined in several ways.

Spring exists, in large part, precisely to decouple things, and it's pretty good at it.

---

*If you want more specific help, you'll probably want to post a concise example of what you think you can't do as cleanly in Spring, allowing folks to map from one paradigm to the other.*

Comment: commands != services. Commands are much more granular, and allow for cross-cutting of concerns. They follow a strict, one-execute-method design pattern, which makes it so easy to switch one with another.

Comment: @user1107412 You're making an artificial distinction. A service can be whatever you want, and as granular as you want.

Comment: @user1107412 The bottom line is that you can inject as many of whatever you want into pretty much anything, call them whatever you want, and each of them can do any operation from large to small.

Comment: I admit that I approach the problem too literally. I think you are right. Can I at least get rid of the controller layer. I use AJAX to call services, which return JSON. Now I still use multiple controllers to do the URL mappings, but what they do is to pass the action onto services. Guess, I can go with one controller only, which invokes the right service according a request parameter map, right?

Comment: @user1107412 Using a single controller again means re-inventing the wheel, but sure, you could. You could also map a generic URL to a single servlet, pull a service/whatever from a map keyed on a URL-embedded parameter(s), etc. You could play games with genericized classes and factories. Many options.

Comment: I don't know. I guess I just don't need controllers in the traditional sense of serving a model object to a jsp view. Guess, I can go with directly calling the services based on some URL mapping, and wire the response to a JSON writer. Gotta check how DispatcherServlet actually does its job. For sure I don't want to annotate my service classes with a bunch of RequestMapping stuff which shouldn't make any sense to them in the general case